# How to store Canvas in Firebase usnig android for realtime Collaboration?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-canvas, firebase-storage

Hello android developers,

I want to create a whiteboard app in android so that users running that app can collaborate using whiteboard.

I've created a simple whiteboard but unable to make it for collaboration in real time.

below is my code for MainActivity.java file -

```
package com.example.cyno.whiteboardcustomview;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Paint paint;
    View view;
    Path path2;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    private float mX, mY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        view = new SketchSheetView(MainActivity.this);

        paint = new Paint();

        path2 = new Path();

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

        relativeLayout.addView(view, new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        paint.setDither(true);

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                path2.reset();

            }
        });

    }

    class SketchSheetView extends View {

        public SketchSheetView(Context context) {

            super(context);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(820, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

            canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        private ArrayList<DrawingClass> DrawingClassArrayList = new ArrayList<DrawingClass>();


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            DrawingClass pathWithPaint = new DrawingClass();
            DatabaseReference myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //Getting root reference
            DatabaseReference myRef = myRef1.child("path2");
            DatabaseReference myRef2 = myRef1.child("paint");
            myRef.setValue(path2.toString());
            myRef2.setValue(paint.toString());

            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {




                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            canvas.drawPath(path2,paint);






            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                path2.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                path2.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                path2.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                pathWithPaint.setPath(path2);

                pathWithPaint.setPaint(paint);

                DrawingClassArrayList.add(pathWithPaint);
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            if (DrawingClassArrayList.size() > 0) {

                canvas.drawPath(
                        DrawingClassArrayList.get(DrawingClassArrayList.size() - 1).getPath(),

                        DrawingClassArrayList.get(DrawingClassArrayList.size() - 1).getPaint());
            }
        }
    }

    public class DrawingClass {

        Path DrawingClassPath;
        Paint DrawingClassPaint;

        public Path getPath() {
            return DrawingClassPath;
        }

        public void setPath(Path path) {
            this.DrawingClassPath = path;
        }


        public Paint getPaint() {
            return DrawingClassPaint;
        }

        public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
            this.DrawingClassPaint = paint;
        }
    }

}
```

code for activity_main.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cyno.whiteboardcustomview.MainActivity">
android:weightSum="100">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Here to clear drawing "
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now what I want to accomplish is that, if I run app on two devices and draw on any once device the same should be draw on another device without any user interaction and vice versa.

I've done the same thing using Firebase Realtime database but, that was using EditText and TextView in android. I can't figure out how to do it with canvas.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dont store the canvas itself, store draw instructions

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you please elaborate? I tried storing path2 and paint in firebase database by converting them into string but can't convert them to Path and Pain again while retrieving from firebase

Comment: Is there any other solution you can suggest? @TimCastelijns